# Script is working correctly on Codepen but not on WP site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dominotrix/details/YVxbGZ/) which works fine, but when I load it on my [Wordpress site](https://artware.gr/thermoplastiki/) it doesn't seem to run correctly.

Here is the JS Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
(function(jQuery, win) {
    jQuery.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
        return this.each(function(i, el) {
            function visPx() {
                var H = jQuery(this).height(),
                    r = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    t = r.top,
                    b = r.bottom;
                return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t > 0 ? H - t : b < H ? b : H));
            }
            visPx();
            jQuery(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window);

jQuery(".kk-img").inViewport(function(px) {
    if (px) jQuery(this).addClass("vsb");
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("vsb", !!px);
});

jQuery(".kk-rec").inViewport(function(px) {
    if (px) jQuery(this).addClass("vsb");
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("vsb", !!px);
});
});
```

Also, the Console of dev tools shows no errors. Anyone has an idea of where should I be looking for to solve this issue?

Thank you for your time.

--- Some more clarification ---

The JS code is adding a class on some elements when these are visible on viewport. Then these elements have some transitions so that they will appear smoothly (you can check what code does on codepen link).

On my website, it is "not working" because the addClass is not added on the elements at all. And I don't know why..

Comment: *it doesn't seem to run correctly* can you be more specific

Comment: Did you enqueue this script ???

Comment: I mean it doesn't do what it is supposed to do: animate elements when they are visible on viewport. While the code is running fine on CodePen, the animation isn't running at all on my site.

Comment: @LebCit Yes. It is inside main.js which is enqued.

Comment: Is the jQuery dependency added to main.js ?

Comment: jQuery is already loaded on my site since I also have other jQuery scripts which run correctly. If you want to take a look this is my main.js

view-source:https://artware.gr/thermoplastiki/wp-content/themes/artware/js/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.js` is not loaded at all !
You can take a look at the source of your code, Ctrl+U or right click and view page source.
Others JS scripts are loaded.
The path of `main.js` is `/js`, I think you have to put it in `/assets/js`
Look again at your `enqueue` function. You could paste it here.
SYA

Comment: It is loaded, why are you saying otherwise? I found another script online for "animate when visible" and now it runs correctly. Didn't figured why the previous script wasn't working.

Comment: go to your [site](https://artware.gr/) and view the source of your code `view-source:https://artware.gr/`. Press Ctrl+F and search for your `main.js`

Comment: You made a mistake mate. This is not the website I am talking about. It is this: https://artware.gr/thermoplastiki/

Comment: Ok my fault :( sorry. Now you directly gave me the link, this is better :) I see that It's working now :) The new script did the work and that's the goal. SYA